# Can I set a policy for certain file in an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket "mybucket" with loads of files in it for example:

```
upload1/123.jpg
public/353.jpg
public/123.jpg
upload2/33.jpg
upload3/423.jpg
```

As I understand it the folders are just a convenience and are just objects anyways. So is it possible to make all the public/* objects public but not the others? How can I do this?

EDIT:
I've done so more reading, would something like this work and not affect anything else?

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1415732583092",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1415732573054",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/public/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this works just fine. You can add this policy to your bucket permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:**",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/public/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then add a file called test.html to your public folder and one of your private folders:

```
<html>
    <body>
    test
    </body>
</html>
```

Then enable static web hosting on the s3 bucket and then go to the S3 endpoint in a web browser (for me in US Standard this would be: `http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/public/test.html`) and you will see the web page displayed, but when you try to access this page through the private bucket you will see that it fails.